# Can we have privileges to access 14 hive folder in Office 365 (SharePoint Online) ?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using SharePoint Online (Office 365) i want to know that can we have privileges to access 14 hive folder in Office 365 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not have access to the "Hive" folder. With SharePoint Online(Office 365 ) you do not have access to any of the back-end and that will include the "Hive" folder